# Centering a quote inside a list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, quoting

I have a very simple problem but I couldn't find a solution yet... How can I center the following quote inside a list compared to the margin of the page:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{outline}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{pmgraph}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{-.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
%--------------------Indention
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item bla bla bla
    \begin{itemize}
        \item bla bla bla 
            \begin{quote}
                \textbf{veryveryveryverylongtextallattachedwithoutanyspacesveryveryveryverylongtextallattachedwithoutanyspaces} 
            \end{quote}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The text looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: it is much easier to answer questions if you provide a small but complete document that helps people debug the problem and test answers, but I would probably just change `quote` to `flushright` so any overflow comes back into the list indent rather than off the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited my question with the small and complete document... I tried with `flushright` as you  suggested and also with `flushleft` but they don't solve the problem...

Comment: if you use `begin{flushright}
                \hspace*{-\textwidth}\textbf{veryveryveryverylongtextallattachedwithoutanyspacesveryveryveryverylongtextallattachedwithoutanyspaces} 
            \end{flushright}` then it is flush to the right margin but it still goes off the page to the left, is your real tex that big (you could use `\small`....

Comment: Cool! That's the answer I was looking for :) it resolved my problem, thank you!

Comment: if you put your last comment as a proper answer, I'll flag it ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle pinging with the hope you become Number 1 in the rankings (OP said he would upvote you if comment becomes answer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
\begin{flushright}
\hspace*{-\textwidth}\textbf{veryveryveryverylongtextallattachedwithoutanyspacesveryveryveryverylongtextallattachedwithoutanyspaces}
\end{flushright}
```

then it is flush to the right margin but it still goes off the page to the left. If your real text is that big you could use `\small`...